# android ble advertising interval change

Tags: android-ble

since Android 5.0 start to support the peripheral device which allow apps to broadcast advertisements. In my app case, I need broadcast every 20ms to 30ms,but I can't find anyway to change the advertising interval. And the default advertising interval is between 20ms to 600ms, which totally can't accept in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have control over the exact millisecond frequency, but you can experiment with using different settings from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings.html such as https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings.html#ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY.

Comment: Yes, I have tied different setting but not too much difference. I hope the adv interval can within 20ms to 30ms.

Answer (score 0):

LOW_LATENCY is the best available that sends a packet about 100mS interval.
If you need a "fast" packet transfer, the workaround option is to create multiple advertisers. And if you create 5 such parallel advertisers, eventually it will reach at around 20-30 mS. Yes, it is possible, but remember, you are flooding the environment with a huge data with 5X times.